# WCF Request Channel Timeout Error

Tags: timeout, wcf, wcf-client

I have an app that calls a WCF service in high frequency. The app starts out working fine and then after a few minutes, every call starts generating this error:

**System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:02:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding.**

I've tried everything I can think of to get around this error, such as:

- Setting multiple concurrencymode on the service:

`[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class ListingService : IListingService`

- Setting higher limits for max concurrent calls/sessions/instances in the service web.config:

`serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100000" maxConcurrentSessions="100000" maxConcurrentInstances="100000"`

- Setting a higher servicepointmanager defaultconnectionlimit on application_start on the service's global.asax:

`protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100000;
        }`

- Making sure I'm closing client connections:

`using (var client = new ListingServiceClient())
                {
                    client.SaveListing(listing);
                    client.Close();
                }`

Here is the services web.config - http://pastebin.com/d9qtZUKN

However, I'm still getting the error. I'm sure that the service call does not take that long. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm that the wcf call wasn't actually taking that long, I created a web method that does nothing and call it multiple times from a test case. After a couple minutes it starts generating the timeout error above. Is there some max connections limit that I'm reaching in IIS 7?

Comment: There is a limit of connections, but it depeonds on a number of cores of a processor, so you have a different problem. Write configuration of the service and the method body in this question.

Comment: Added a link to the services web.config code. There's nothing to add for the method body because it's an empty method, ie) public void Test() { }

Comment: Try to set InstanceContextMode=PerCall in the attribute ServiceBehavior. Also try to remove both binding and behavior configurations from the service defination, test it with default settings. Another possible reason of the problem - you test many times from a single computer and it is a problem of client.

Comment: Also you can create a sample project that reproduces this problem and provide me a link to test it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the db timing out which caused WCF to time out.

Comment: correct, sendTimeout fires when a particular call is not finished in a given time interval, so some call stuck for 2 minutes, you can catch `TimeoutException` to see more details